# Different integer value inside and outside a loop

Tags: c, cs50

I would like to use an integer created inside a loop, but when I use it outside a loop, it gives a different value than inside. I need to extract every second digit from an integer: `17121` then multiply it by `2`.

In this case I extracted by the loop below the digits `7` and `2`, and were multiplied by `2`, which gives the value of `int sum = 414`.

```
int cardNum = 17121;
int otherDigits;
int sum = 0;

do {
    otherDigits = cardNum % 100 / 10 * 2;
    cardNum = cardNum / 100;
    sum = otherDigits;
    printf("%i", sum);
} while (cardNum > 99);
```

The problem comes when I attempt to use `int sum;` outside the loop, because the value `int sum;` becomes `14` instead of `414`.

The next step would be adding the extracted digits as `4 + 1 + 4`, however outside of the loop I can add only the digits of the value of `14`, or `1 + 4`.
Don't understand why the value of `int sum;` is different inside and outside the loop.

Comment: You're not adding anything, anywhere

Comment: Note that calling `sum` does not match it's use in the code. You are not updating it's value, just setting it to `otherDigits` in every iteration.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code ? Because I don't see your usage of "sum" variable outside the loop.
Please, provide an MCVE code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

Inside the loop, the value of sum is first 4, then 14. When printed, this gives the string "414" because there is no space between prints. This might give you the illusion that the value inside and outside the loop is different but in fact it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You get the output `414` because you print without any kind of separator inside the loop.

The loop iterates twice: The first time it prints `4`, then the second time it prints `14`. When those run together you get `414`.

Print with a trailing newline and you will see it work, printing `4` on one line and `14` on another.

The end result of `sum` both inside the last iteration of the loop and after the loop is `14`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "move" the former digits "out of the way" for the next ones:

```
do
{
  otherDigits = cardNum % 100 / 10 * 2;
  cardNum = cardNum / 100;
  if (otherDigits > 9)
    sum = sum * 100;
  else
    sum = sum * 10;
  sum = sum + otherDigits;
  printf("%i", sum);
}
while (cardNum > 99);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to achieve! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.